# iOS localized text not appearing on real device

Tags: ios, localization, runtime-error

I have localized my app. However, the storyboard text is failing in 1 instance. In Xcode, previewing the view controller for the required display language shows the correct text, and running on the simulator also works.

However, when running on a real device (with the same display language set), the non-localized text is shown (ie the localization lookup is failing).

This only happens for one particular piece of text, all the others appear correctly.
In the Main.strings file, all formatting for this failing bit of text is the same as the others.

Does anyone know why? Anyone know how to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: try cleaning your `derivedData`. May be it is caching issue